# Setting cookie via javascript, doesn't work in Safari

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, browser, setcookie

Setting cookie via javascript, but it isn't set in Safari.

Im making online shopping that will update the items everywhere automatically. Example: when you open 2tab or more, 1tab for product detail, 1tab for checkout page, they will update everywhere when there is a change to the shopping cart.
It uses cookie, im setting cookie in JavaScript, then get it in php. And there is no problem in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE10. Only Safari that make me confused.
you can try this:

[For product detail](http://artsitektur.divren.co.id/furniture/office/18/)

[For checkout page](http://artsitektur.divren.co.id/order/)

this is one of the codes :

`document.cookie = 'countedPrice=' + countedPrice + '; expires=' + now.toGMTString() + '; path=/';`

Need help! Thanks man!

Comment: Please explain: an *error* occurs, or it's just the cookie that isn't set?

Comment: @MaxArt owww.. im sorry, just the cookie isn't set

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: :( is it because of the setting in the browser? there is no error, just not set in ie10 and safari

Comment: Now it works for IE10.
But not for Safari. Would you help?

Comment: Alright, finally, it works! I just remove the , (comma) from the cookie data, and works in Safari. Thank you All